# Show and hide multiple divs with same class name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show / hide an infinite number of divs all with the same class name. I use JQuery for this. See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g2hw6hh/2/

I tried to use the next selector in JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsonInfo").hide(); // it's obvious
  $(".showJSON").click(function() {  // on click...

    $(".jsonInfo")
      .hide()  // ...hide all other previus opened elements...
      .eq($(this).index('.showJSON')) // ... select right one by index of clicked .showJSON element...
       .toggle(); // and show/hide it
  });
});
```

How do I fix this and get the divs to show/hide independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.next() pick next sibling element which have ".jsonInfo" class. Because your next sibilings are only buttons and div's with ".row" class, you need to use something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.jsonInfo").hide(); // it's obvious
  $("button.showJSON").click(function() {  // on click...
    
    $("div.jsonInfo")
      .hide()  // ...hide all other previus opened elements...
      .eq($(this).index('.showJSON')) // ... select right one by index of clicked .showJSON element...
       .toggle(); // and show/hide it
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showJSON">Show JSON 1</button>
<button class="showJSON">Show JSON 2</button>
<button class="showJSON">Show JSON 3</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 1</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 3</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

But you need to remember, you need to have the same amount of **button.showJSON** and **div.jsonInfo** in the same order.

Comment: why are you doing index() - 1?

Comment: Good point - i forgot about to set '.showJson' class to index method. Try now.

Comment: would you mind to look at this updated fiddle with your solution? it does not seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/1g2hw6hh/2/

Comment: Yeah, but: 1st: In your fiddle is other HTML than in my example, and 2nd: you dont have dots with class names. Check this [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1g2hw6hh/4/)

Comment: You just remove ".hide()" from line 6 and restore .toggle() back in line 8

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value (or a data-attribute if you prefer that) into each of your buttons and then on the onclick - get that value (or data attribute) and using .eq(), show the specific div. In effect when you click the first button - you show the first related div, when you click the second button - you hide the visible divs and show the specified div. Not e that this requires a zero indexed numbering of the buttons.

You can also simplify the code for creating the buttons (if they all have the same basic structure) by using a loop and using the index of that loop when you put the content into the page)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsonInfo").hide();
  $(".showJSON").click(function() {
    $(".jsonInfo").hide();
    var showJsonVal = $(this).val();
    $(".jsonInfo").eq(showJsonVal).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showJSON" value="0">Show JSON 1</button>
<button class="showJSON" value="1">Show JSON 2</button>
<button class="showJSON" value="2">Show JSON 3</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 1</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jsonInfo">
    <h6>JSON 3</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make them all toggle doing this? Without running into the situation where I toggle JSON 2 and JSON 1 shows up?

Comment: not sure what you mean - try running the code snippet in my answer - toggling JSON 2 hides any visible div and only showsJSON 2. Is that not what you want?

Comment: please see this fiddle with your solution, not working http://jsfiddle.net/1g2hw6hh/3/

Comment: DUDE!!!! - I looked at that fiddle and you have to have a value on the button for the $(this).val() to work - as in my answer (<button class="showJSON" value="0">Show JSON 1</button>). try copying both the HTML portion and the js portion from my answer

Comment: i completely missed that sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to show/hide NEXT to button div - you need to rewrite your html :

```
<button class="showJSON">Show JSON 1</button>
<div class="jsonInfo">
<h6>JSON 1</h6>
</div>
...
```

but if you need to hide by button's class, you need smth like that :

```
<button class="showJSON" class-to-hide="jsonInfo">Show JSON 1</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsonInfo").hide();

    $(".showJSON").click(function() {  
      var cls = $(this).attr('class-to-hide');        
      $("div."+cls).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: I just want to be able to toggle showing/ hiding divs using their respective buttons

Comment: @jebmarcus ok, you need second case in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle them independently you need to use ids or data-ids.

```
<button id="1" class="showJSON">Show JSON 1</button>
<!-- infinitely many buttons...--> 

<div data-id="1" class="jsonInfo">
   <h6>JSON 1</h6>
</div>
<!-- infinitely many divs...-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k0fL2aho/

Comment: This is not what i am looking for as it does not allow scaling up to infinite divs

Comment: It does check out the javascript's jsfiddle.